# Delete all files in a directory matching a time pattern

Tags: shell

I am taking one of important folder every day backup by using cron. That folder name it will store with the current date.

Now my requirement is i need to keep only the current day and last two days backup.

i.e I want to keep only:

- test_2016-11-04.tgz
- test_2016-11-03.tgz
- test_2016-11-02.tgz

Remaining folder it has to delete automatically. Please let us know how to do in shell script.

Below is my backup folder structure.

```
test_2016-10-30.tgz    test_2016-11-01.tgz    test_2016-11-03.tgz
test_2016-10-31.tgz    test_2016-11-02.tgz    test_2016-11-04.tgz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could append end of backup script;

```
find ./backupFolder -name "test_*.tgz" -mtime +3 -type f -delete
```

also use this;

```
ls -1 test_*.tgz | sort -r | awk 'NR > 3 { print }' | xargs -d '\n' rm -f --
```

Answer (score 1):

With `ls -lrt | head -n -3 | awk '{print $9}`
you can print all but the last 3 files in your directory.
Passing this output into `rm` you obtain the result desidered.

Comment: Worth reading: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/40596)

Answer (score 0):

Generate an array on files you want to keep:

```
names=()
for d in {0..2}; do
    names+=( "test_"$(date -d"$d days ago" "+%Y-%m-%d")".tgz" )
done
```

so that it looks like this:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${names[@]}"
test_2016-11-04.tgz
test_2016-11-03.tgz
test_2016-11-02.tgz
```

Then, loop through the files and [keep those that are not in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15901346/1983854):

```
for file in test_*.tgz; do
    [[ ! ${names[*]} =~ "$file" ]] && echo "remove $file" || echo "keep $file"
done
```

If ran on your directory, this would result on an output like:

```
remove test_2016-10-30.tgz
remove test_2016-10-31.tgz
remove test_2016-11-01.tgz
keep test_2016-11-02.tgz
keep test_2016-11-03.tgz
keep test_2016-11-04.tgz
```

So now it is just a matter or replacing those `echo` with something more meaningful like `rm`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its helped me a lot